# Minimo, maximo y promedio de una consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

```
SELECT COUNT(id_casa) c1
FROM arrienda
GROUP BY id_casa
```

Esta consulta me trae las veces que aparece repetido el id_casa de una tabla
Ejemplo

```
    id_casa a1, está 4 veces
    id_casa a2, está 6 veces
    id_casa a3, está 11 veces
```

Necesito que la consulta me de como resultado min 4, max, 11, avg 7.

Comment: Como consejo, en este tipo de preguntas, la estructura de tu tabla y algunos datos de prueba se consideran elementos útiles para poder reproducir tu escenario y apoyarte de forma mas efectiva, considera leer [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas los valores mínimos, máximos y el promedio de tu consulta los puedes obtener, usando to consulta como "expresión tabular".

Por ejemplo:

```
select 
  min(c1) as min_c1,
  max(c1) as max_c1,
  avg(c1) as promedio_c1
from (
  SELECT COUNT(id_casa) c1 FROM arrienda GROUP BY id_casa
) x
```

Comment: Gracias, amigo.